# Visual Studio 2015 replaces private property with public property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, visual-studio-2015, automatic-properties

When i have a private field in c#, let's say `private string a`, which is used in the constructor like this:

```
a = "1";
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

and i create a public property via: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
Visual Studio 2015 automtically replaces all private fields with the public one, means:

```
A = "1";
Console.WriteLine(A);
```

Why do VS has this default behaviour, and can it be turned off?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite get it, sorry. Did you mean `When i have a private *field*` instead of `When i have a private property`?

Comment: Yep, i will change the question

Comment: Are you using ReSharper? In that case, when you press Ctrl+R+E, there's a dialog where you can set the visibility of your property.

Comment: OK, so essentially you refactor a field into a property then. Well, maybe someone thought that the default accessibility for a property should be, or rather would be, public. Otherwise you wouldn't have turned that field into a property in the first place. Just saying...

Comment: No, clean visual studio enterprise 2015

Comment: Because it just another one of the dozens of Roslyn bugs in VS2015.  Type Ctrl+. instead and it will do less damage.

Comment: Use [ctrl] + [.] to view Quick Actions, and choose the second form of "Encapsulate Field". Slightly more cumbersome, but it will do what you want. No shortcut available though.

Comment: Ok, do i have to report the behaviour?